# Add key in known_hosts file in ChromeOS

Tags: ssh, google-chrome-os, crosh

With the very limited ChromeOS crosh shell, how do I add a host key to my known_hosts file in ChromeOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to add your key to the Chrome OS shell. If you are in developer mode you can add your key. You can also install the Secure Shell app from the Chrome Web Store and add your key within that app. The app is the best way to go if you don't want to use developer mode, although it still has some bugs to work out.